# Can not convert the data that contains Int64 type to json

Tags: dart, dart-server

I am using mongo_dart.
Some field contains the `Int64` type.
I tried to convert the `Map<String, dynamic>` type that receive from MongoDB to the `JSON` by using the `jsonEncode` function but I got this error:

```
Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'Int64'
```

How to fix this?

Should I change the field type to `String`?

Should I create a function that converts every element in the `Map<String, dynamic>` from `Int64` to `Int`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is based on JavaScript, and JavaScript numbers are IEEE-754 double-precision floating-point numbers (`double`s), which have a 53-bit significand.  They cannot store all 64-bit integers without loss of precision. (JSON implementations can vary in how numbers are stored, but if you care about interoperability, then you should assume `double`s as the lowest common denominator.)

Therefore, if you use the full range of 64-bit integers, you're better off storing 64-bit integers as strings.

If 53-bits are sufficient for you, or if you don't care about interoperability and your JSON values will be read and written only by Dart VM code (not Dart for the Web), then you can use `int`s everywhere and not bother with `Int64`.

Comment: Thank you. I change this field from the `timestamp` (int) to `utc` (string).